# Working with SharePoint 2007 List

Tags: sharepoint, list

I need help solving an issue.

I have a list that will be used to track training progress for employees. To simplify it, the list is called Training and the following are the columns:

- Employee Name (Text)
- Training Event 1 (Choice)
- Training Event 2 (Choice)
- Training Event 3 (Choice)

The Training Event X fields are of type choice with the following options:

- Completed
- Required
- N/A

What I am trying to do is display a bar graph with all of the Training Events on the X-Axis and the number of occurrences of Completed, Required, or N/A displayed by bars.

I am also open to just retrieving the values for use in content editor. In this case, I wouldn't use a graph. I can just display "X employees have completed Training Event 1 and Y employees are required to complete it."

I am used to dealing with SQL where you can run custom queries, however, I am trying to figure out how to do this with SharePoint lists.

Notes:

- I do not have access to SharePoint Designer software
- I have the ability to use Bamboo Web Parts

Thank you and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Try Visifire for SharePoint webpart to visualize SharePoint list Data. You can easily and quickly Create stunning charts in SharePoint(2007/2010) without writing any code!

First I suggest you to checkout this 60 seconds video in release blog [here](http://www.visifire.com/blog/2011/11/02/sharepoint-charts/).

**Now follow the steps below**

1. Download Visifire For SharePoint from [here](http://www.visifire.com/download_silverlight_wpf_controls.php#sharepoint) and install it.
2. Install Silverlight from the link [here](http://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/Get-Started/Install/Default.aspx).
3. Restart your browsers and start creating charts in your sharepoint page.

**Documentation links:**

1) http://www.visifire.com/documentation/Visifire_Documentation/VisifireForSharePoint/Visifire_for_SharePoint_2007.htm

2) http://www.visifire.com/documentation/Visifire_Documentation/VisifireForSharePoint/Quick_Start_with_Visifire_For_SharePoint_.htm

Full Disclosure: I work for Visifire

Comment: Please add a disclosure for your affiliation with this service.

Answer (score 0):

If you switch the list to DataSheet view, and click the slider on the far righ-hand-side of the Datasheet grid, there are options to chart with Excel. Maybe you could use that to generate the barchart from the data?

See image below:

[image]